# Two-way mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I have the following mapping:

```
CreateMap<LayoutRequest, Layout>();
CreateMap<Layout, LayoutRequest>()
    .ForMember(m => m.Settings, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

It works fine but are we able to do it by single line? I thought it should solve my case:

```
CreateMap<LayoutRequest, Layout>()
    .ForSourceMember(m => m.Settings, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

But it doesn't work. It says there is no mapping for `Settings`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AutoMapper has a "ReverseMap" feature that can be used like below.

```
CreateMap<Layout, LayoutRequest>()
    .ForMember(m => m.Settings, opt => opt.Ignore())
    .ReverseMap();
```